# jQuery custom content scroller not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

i'm trying to use the jquery custom scrollbar library but it's not displaying the custom scrollbar. i dont know what i'm doing wrong i'n not getting any errors and i think i pathed the files correctly and loaded everything in the right order. I could really use some help with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Huppit</title>

    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--custom scrollbar-->
    <link href="scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body style="height:2000px">
    <!--bootstrap and jquery-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--custom scrollbar-->
    <script src="scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <!--own scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").mCustomScrollbar();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it is a problem with your path to your custom scrollbar libraries. Have you tried adding a slash or dot slash in front of the paths to the scrollbar css and js?

Comment: Additional to what Ece wrote, use a div to apply the scrollbar to, not the body.

Comment: doesnt seem to make a differnence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/dGqvgm).

To get it to work, I had to do two things. First, I had to put the element with scrollbar, `body_content` in this example, inside a `container` div. Second, I had to change `overflow` to `hidden` on both `container` div and `body` to get rid of the duplication of vertical scrollbar.

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $(".body_content").mCustomScrollbar({
       theme: "dark",
       scrollButtons: {enable:true}
   });
});
```

**CSS**

```
body, .container {
   overflow: hidden;
}
.body_content {
   position: relative;
   max-height: 500px;
   background: #ddd;
}
```

By the way, according to the plugin documentation, you always need to set either `width` or `max-width` for horizontal scrollbar, and `height` or `max-height` for vertical scrollbar. Also, you can do it using a variable defined in the plugin.

Comment: works for me to thanks, kind of weird that all this isnt described on the official website though

Comment: It is a very nice plugin, cross-platform, many useful themes and functionalities. But as you said, documentation is not straightforward.

Comment: yeah it looks really nice which is a shame because i looked at some other custom scrollbar plugins that atleast worked but didnt have as many options as this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Huppit</title>

    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
    html,body{height:100%;}
    </style>

    <!--custom scrollbar-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.1.3/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--custom scrollbar-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.1.3/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!--Add a lot of text here-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(window).load(function(){
                $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollButtons:{
                        enable:true
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Following this example http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/full_page_demo.html

Comment: no still no luck btw i dont thnk their would even be a scroll bar with html,body{height:100%;} in the css

Comment: It works for me but you have to add content that fills the whole page otherwise the scrollbar won't show up.

Comment: I used the code here http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/full_page_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code on your website:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom Scroller</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.1.3/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.1.3/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".body-wrapper").mCustomScrollbar({
              theme: "inset-dark",
              scrollButtons: {enable:true}
          });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html { height:100%; min-height:100%; }
        body { margin:0; }
        .body-wrapper { height:100%; background-color:#eee; overflow:hidden;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body-wrapper">
        <h1>Custom Scroller</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i run this myself i do see some stuff that resembles the scroll bar but it doesnt function and the default scroll bar is also still present

Comment: I´m sorry ... I changed the code one more time. Run the example. It should work now. The Problem was I set the height of the body wrapper to 2000px but the wrapper should have 100% height. The dummy `p`now has 2000px for example now the Custom Scroller is visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it appears to me that for some reason the only time the scrollbar appears is when their is a big enough div on the page and it also seems the original scrollbar needs to be hidden. I dont know if this is an overseight from the developers or i'm overlooking something but it's a very weird implementation especially since it's not described on the plugins page.

Comment: I built it again in an external fiddle. 1) All JavaScript files have to beloaded via https here in js fiddle, in your HTML File you could also use http as your page is not running under https I think 2) First load jQuery, Second jquery.mousewheel, third jquery.mCustomScrollbar https://jsfiddle.net/roland_krinner/2p2s6Lk3/2/ - My Example aboth should also work now, I´m sorry also here I had to reference all Scripts with `https://`

Answer (score -1):

Be sure your script files at the right folder. I changed them to CDN links and put all scripts between `<head></head>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Huppit</title>

    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--custom scrollbar-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.1.3/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--custom scrollbar-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.1.3/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:2000px">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").mCustomScrollbar();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does that work for you? because that code doesnt work on my end